# Pulse width parameter in VI Characteristic curve of Diode

Tags: diodes

I was referring to the datasheet of IN4001 from [Vishay](http://www.vishay.com/docs/88503/1n4001.pdf)
In Fig.4 (Typical Instantaneous Forward Characteristics), pulsewidth=300usec 1% duty cycle is given. I would like to know what this parameter is? In datasheet, there is no mention of pulse width it looks.

[image: VI Characteristics]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pulse width and duty cycle is an explanation of **how they measure the instantaneous forward voltage parameter**. This is how you would set up the test equipment to verify that the diodes meet specifications.

You can't measure the voltage without putting current through the diode. You can't put current through the diode without changing the die temperature, so the forward voltage for longer pulse widths and larger duty cycles would appear to be lower or higher because the die heats during the pulse or over a number of pulses.

For low currents the forward voltage decreases with temperature as you might expect for a diode, but for extremely high currents the Vf temperature coefficent actually goes through a null at something like 10-20A and becomes positive because the non-ideal resistive term dominates, and it has a positive tempco.

The Tj, although specified as 25°C cannot remain constant.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.Just by increasing DC supply voltage and using a current limiting  resistance, can't we measure the voltage across the diode? Why the input has to be of pulsing type?

Comment: The diode will quickly be destroyed if you put 10-20A through it. Think of the power dissipation. If your current is low (<< 1A) then you can do it with DC with reasonable accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the diode junction thickness is 10 microns. The thermal timeconstant of that is 1.14 microseconds. In other words, most of the heat generated within the junction will not have time to leave.

The diode is probably 100-300 micron thick[ thinned-wafers, or standard-wafers], with thermal timeconstants of 114uS to 1milliSecond.

A 300uS pulse simply works with the fact that the heat mostly remains inside the silicon during a 300uS pulse.